# PC restarts on power outtage despite having a UPS

Tags: power-supply, battery, power, power-management, ups

Unfortunately where I live I do not have 24/7 electricity.

My new PC rig which is considered to be a high-end(gaming) 
system is connected to a brand new APS/UPS that have these specs:

DC-AC Inverter-Pure Sine wave
1600VA/12V
5 AMP
Charge 20A
97% peak efficiency with power factor correction.

According to the company's technical support, they say it 
can provide stable 800 watt on 12V and even non-stable 1000 watt.

Of course I have a brand new Car battery (more-like truck 
battery) "N200 12v 200ah" connected to the inverter.

And I'm using a tier 1 PSU considered-among-enthuasiats 
that is Corsair AX860i — 860 Watt 80 PLUS® Platinum 
Certified Fully-Modular PSU with over current and 
undercurrent protection.

While I'm gaming, my computer restarts when a main power 
cut occurs, the UPS does take over but while it does the 
computer restarts.

Though, if I'm not gaming(low power consumption) it doesn't 
restart. And the UPS would take over without any interruption.

Taking into consideration that my GPU is MSI 980 gtx GAMING 4g.

I calculated my RIG power consumption online and under load 
it doesn't exceed 550 watt.

The only "non-high-quality" parts in this case I would think of, is the surge protector (or surge suppressor) that connects everything to everything! And there are two of them, one for UPS < main power and the other for UPS output < RIG.

What may be causing the restart when power cuts off while gaming? And is it going to shorten the life-span of my components or possibly cause damage? Also would you think it boils down to large switchover time?

Thanks.

Comment: Consider getting an online UPS if what you have is either an offline or line interactive model.

Comment: What's the wattage rating of the UPS? Are you sure they said 800 watt? What's the make/model?

Comment: Yes and the technician tested it live on 8 lamps (800watt).

Comment: The fact it works fine when your not gaming suggests the UPS is undersized.  I would use a tp link kasa kp115 or similar to monitor you actual consumption and not calculate it.

Answer (score 1):

Power, simply put, is volt times current. So the 800 Watt output should match the current rating. Unfortunately, it doesn't. The specified output current of 5 Amp doesn't lead to 800 Watt - nobody uses 160 Volt.

Instead, you'd be looking at either a 550 Watt UPS (110 V * 5A) or a 1150 Watt UPS (230 V * 5A). Considering the observed failures under load, I'm assuming it's the first. So, you are probably looking at a somewhat underdimensioned UPS.

I'm also surprised by your use of two surge protectors. A UPS never, never ever should produce a surge. Hence, remove the surge protector between your PC and the UPS.

Comment: Do you mean the AC output socket on the UPS? Because it mentions 220V AC output, and in-regards to the surge protectors, they are used for the distance between the ups and the rig.

Comment: Yeah - if that's a 220V output, 5A, then it is possibly old. Europe moved from 220V to 230V,except for the UK which moved down from 240V to 230 V. But most hardware doesn't care about that. The point is that 220V, 5A should give you 1100W (or 1150), not 800. There's some nitpicking about "power factor", but in your case that factor is 0.99 so you should still get 1089W.

Comment: Thanks, I read somewhere that it could be from the Motherboard "Asus anti-surge protection". Now in this scenario do you think disabling it from Bios to give it a try would have any issues or risk of damaging my components?

Comment: I don't believe that such a surge protection is really reliable anyway, so the risk doesn't really change.

Comment: Meh, didn't work. Weird thing tho if I switched off the main power manually, I wouldn't have an issue, although if the power cuts off automatically, the issue occurs. At this point I believe it's just the large switchover time

Answer (score 1):

UPS battery backups don't output 'clean' power.  When the UPS switches from wall power to battery power, there's a switch in the waveform of the power being supplied.

PSUs that utilize Active Power Switching will see this changeover as unclean power, and restart or shutdown.  I had the exact same issue with my servers for over a year until I troubleshooted and found out what it was.

You can read another article about it here:

https://nileshgr.com/2015/03/22/the-pc-reset-problem-with-active-pfc-smps-and-ups

Answer (score 0):

Since your PC **restarts** when you switch off the mains, the UPS does provide enough power. Otherwise your PC would simply shut down and you wouldn't be able to start it while on UPS.

This means the switchover time is most probably the root cause. You'll need a [Line-Interactive](http://www.pcguide.com/ref/power/ext/ups/typesLineInt-c.html) UPS, which has no switchover at all.

Obviously, such abrupt restarts are no good for both your UPS and your PC, so besides the inconvenience of sudden restarts your current setup does shorten the lifetime of the electronics.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue and I found no help on the internet but today I figured out what the problem was. I will not go into much technical things. I bought this UPS ( CYBERPOWER UT-1500E) which is rated for 1500VA / 900Watt. The PC pulls maximum of 400watt on load. So today I changed this UPS to a Frontech ( 1000VA / 600Watt) UPS, which to my surprise, worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).