# What would cause a fully powered off workstation to turn itself back on?

Tags: power-supply, power, ups

I have an old workstation that I want to keep fully powered off when I'm not around. Just recently I came home to find it powered on, even though I didn't touch it. There is no one else around (and not even an animal like a cat) that could have touched it and caused it to power on.

Further, the system is not connected to any network via ethernet, has no wi-fi card, it's connected to a UPS so a power interruption is very unlikely, and "boot on LAN" and "boot on network activity" are disabled in its BIOS.

Is there anything I can do to figure out why it turned itself on? And aside from removing it from its power source completely, is there anything I can do to stop this from happening in the future?

Comment: Wake On X (eg Wake on LAN) or BIOS auto scheduler could do this.

Comment: @davidgo Wake on LAN is disabled, and I don't think its BIOS has an automatic scheduler feature. At the very least I've never configured it.

Comment: Does the UPS keep a log of its own activity, in case something is revealed there?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Alas it does not

Comment: Does the BIOS have a "Restore on AC/Power Loss" (or similar wording) setting somewhere (they could have hidden it)? Older BIOSes tended to have that.

Comment: ...[PC restarts on power outtage despite having a UPS](https://superuser.com/a/1059129/272824)

Answer (score 0):

Type ncpa.cpl into the run menu

[image]

Now for each net-adapter inside the resulting window right click and go properties

[image]

Now click configure and go to power management tab. You want the following 3 boxes to be unticked:

[image]